# Plotting Real-Time Data With OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, real-time

I'm playing with OpenGL for the first time using `GLSurfaceView`. My first project will be to plot some real time data as a line chart using `GL_LINE_STRIP`. However, before I get knee-deep in code, I'm looking for some advice as to how best to approach the problem of plotting real-time data using OpenGL and Android.

I guess the simplest approach would be to instantiate a `ByteBuffer` of fixed length to store the vertex data (x & y values) at the front-end, and then providing your data is streaming in at a fixed rate, it should be a simple case of updating only the y values in the `ByteBuffer` using its `put` methods. However, this will rely on the assumption that Android passes the data through to the native environment at accurate rate e.g. If the data is streaming in at 50ms can I be sure that Android will pass and update the `ByteBuffer` at 50ms intervals? Is this a typical method to adopt for real time plotting?

If not, I guess it's better to work with 'real time data' and calculate a value for x with each y value, and pass both values through to the `ByteBuffer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Are you sure that you really need OpenGL for this? It sounds like something you should be able to do using a custom Android view and the Android [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) drawing API.

---

That said, if you want to go for a simple OpenGL solution, update your ByteBuffer in memory. Every time a new data point arrives: remove the oldest entry from the front, append the newest to the back. After you have updated your buffer, upload it to the GPU again with `glBufferData()`.

When it's time to redraw with `glDrawElement(GL_LINE_STRIP, ...)`, make sure to update your view matrix so that you "scroll along" with new data points.

Note that this technique is **not efficient**. You first update all vertex data on the CPU, then you transfer all vertex data to the GPU every 50ms. However, if you have only a few hundred vertices on screen, it should not matter too much.

---

A more efficient solution would maintain a [Circular Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) on GPU memory. Every time new data arrives, you replace the oldest data point using `glBufferSubData()`. This is more efficient, but it requires you to keep track of where the oldest data point is stored.

Comment: Great answer. I'm exploring all options, including Canvas, but like the idea of OpenGL if nothing more that to get a good understanding of how graphics are rendered and how to do it efficiently. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a similar task, updating data each 200 ms in a buffer containing up to 100k values and running quite fluently so far (no idea if Canvas would be more suitable). But I am still looking for more optimization, there are several hints around I want to try out:

1. [Vertex Specification Best Practices > Dynamic VBO](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices#Dynamic_VBO)

   > If you will be updating a small section, use glBufferSubData. If you
   >   will update the entire VBO, use glBufferData (this information
   >   reportedly comes from a nVidia document). However, another approach
   >   reputed to work well when updating an entire buffer is to call
   >   glBufferData with a NULL pointer, and then glBufferSubData with the
   >   new contents. The NULL pointer to glBufferData lets the driver know
   >   you don't care about the previous contents so it's free to substitute
   >   a totally different buffer, and that helps the driver pipeline uploads
   >   more efficiently.
2. [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS > Best Practices for Working with Vertex Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html)

   > You can use the glBufferSubData function to update buffer contents,
   >   but doing so incurs a performance penalty because it flushes the
   >   command buffer and waits for all commands to complete. Double or
   >   triple buffering can reduce this performance cost somewhat. (See “Use
   >   Double Buffering to Avoid Resource Conflicts.”)
3. [iPhone 3D Programming > Boosting Performance with Vertex Buffer Objects](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001814/ch03.html#ch03_id36001334)

   > To modify the contents of an existing VBO, you can use
   >   glBufferSubData:
   >   [...]
   >
   > The only difference between this and glBufferData is the offset parameter,
   >   which specifies a number of bytes from the start of the VBO. Note that
   >   glBufferSubData should be used only to update a VBO that has
   >   previously been initialized with glBufferData.
   >
   > We won’t be using glBufferSubData in any of the samples in this book.
   >   Frequent updates with glBufferSubData should be avoided for best
   >   performance, but in many scenarios it can be very useful.